# Limits of this function in the polar system

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

Given is the following double integral -
$$\iint\limits_{D}\frac{1}{(x^2+ y^2)^2}\,dy\,dx$$

$D$ is the region for $x\in[1,2]$ and $y\in[0,\sqrt{2x-x^2}]$

How would the limits of integration be derived if one was to convert the coordinate system from Cartesian to polar?

So far, I can only understand that $\theta$ would hold an upper bound of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with a lower bound of $0$ and could derive by algebra that $r$ would hold an upper bound of $2\cos\theta$. By the same algebra, the lower bound for $r$ turns out as $0$.

[Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl5Ti.png)

Here's my go at finding bounds for $r$
$$y = \sqrt{2x - x^2}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = 2x$$
$$r^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta) = 2r\cos\theta$$
$$r^2 - 2r\cos\theta = 0$$
Thus, $r$ is found to be $0, 2\cos\theta$

From a solution that I found, the lower bound for $r$ was given as $\sec\theta$. Could someone please explain how that came to be? I've been at it for a day now

Comment: The region drawing is incorrect. It is only the right half of that circle.

Comment: Because you are only integrating over the top right quarter-circle, the lower bound for $r$ must be $\sec(\theta)$. The upper bound for $r$ and the bounds for $\theta$ are correct. Also, remember that $dA$ in polar coordinates is $r\ dr\ d\theta$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi It is the top right quadrant

Comment: thanks! although this is my first post here so i was trying out the features of the editor here and pasted a snip from my discussion with a peer. No excuses! Thanks again.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri you are right it's only the upper right section

Comment: Darn. It's the same question. Sorry for the inconveniences everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct except for the lower bound which is given by

$$x=1\implies r=\sec\theta$$

The integral in polar coordinates is

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{\sec\theta}^{2\cos\theta} \frac{1}{r^3}\:drd\theta$$

Comment: This is what i wanted to understand. How did you arrive at the lowerbound?

Comment: @AnupamDash the integral starts at the hard lines $x=1$ and $y=0$ from the bounds you are given

Comment: OOOh! Got it! I analysed $r\cos\theta$ with regards to the bounding area.